# How to make an interface for typescript module-files in the whole directory?

Tags: typescript, module, interface

I have `api` directory and I want to specify this interface for module-files in this directory.:

```
export interface API<
  Model extends BaseModel,
  Filters extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Permissions extends PermissionsType<string> = PermissionsType<string>
> {
  create?: (data: Model) => HttpClientResponse<Model>
  destroy?: (id: Pick<Model, 'id'>) => HttpClientResponse
  update?: (data: Model) => HttpClientResponse<Model>
  useList?: (filters?: Filters) => ApiHookResult<PaginationData<Model>>
  useItem?: (id: Pick<Model, 'id'>) => ApiHookResult<Model>
  usePermissions?: () => ApiHookResult<Permissions>
}
```

So that each file in `api` directory can contain only these functions. How can I do it?

Comment: Can't you import the `API` interface to each of the apis in that directory? Or are you looking for a "do it only once" kind of solution?

Comment: @dwosk Yes, I want this interface as a constraint for api modules.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your requirements are but if you want to assign interface `API` to each of your apis, just import `API` into each of those files and assign it to your api class using `implements`.

fooApi.ts:

```
import { API } from 'types.ts' // or wherever you declare this type

class FooApi implements API {
  ...
}
```

barApi.ts:

```
import { API } from 'types.ts' // or wherever you declare this type

class BarApi implements API {
  ...
}
```

Comment: In this case API interface is a constraint for classes but not for the files.

Comment: so you want your actual files to be type safe? I'm not sure typescript can do that.

Comment: Yes, since classes make me import the whole API pack even if I need only one method.

Comment: I think may be module declarations can help.